# Remove woocommerce cart updated message?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When I update the quantity in the cart, It will display "cart updated" message.

How do I remove or disable it? I just dont want to show up. Just the "cart updated message"

Answer (score 2):

years later i was looking for the same thing. here is the answer. you can alter the message, that pops-up, when you change cart quantities via `woocommerce_add_message` filter.

change it:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', 'se53209949_woocommerce_add_message', 10, 0);
function se53209949_woocommerce_add_message() {
    return __('your message', 'YOUR-THEME-TEXTDOMAIN');
}
```

remove it:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', '__return_false');
```

Comment: Using the `__return_false` filter broke the ajax functionality on my add coupon and remove coupon ajax feature on checkout.  Took me a while to figure out this was why the ajax success call was returning an empty string.

Comment: @bbruman sorry for that. i guess `'__return_empty_string'` would be the proper value then? can you try that out?

Comment: No problem, just letting others know if they encounter the same situation.  For now I just used CSS to target the selector with a `display:none;` and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this appropraitely

```html
add_filter('gettext', 'wpse_124400_woomessages', 10, 3);

/**
* change some WooCommerce labels
* @param string $translation
* @param string $text
* @param string $domain
* @return string
*/
function wpse_124400_woomessages($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ($domain == 'woocommerce') {
        if ($text == 'Cart updated.') {
            $translation = 'Basket updated.';
        }
    }

    return $translation;
}
```

But make use of this [wordpress function](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) to change its message
 Hope this works?